# how to laravel 5.7 http id hidden

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am using laravel 5.7 and want to hide the id in url. Now my url show like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-stock/87
```

I want to hide this id number. Anybody example? Thank you all.

Comment: use method 'POST' instead of 'GET'

Comment: you can conver id to json_encode and rever it with json_decode

Comment: Route::get('/add-stock/{id}','StockController@addStOCk');

Answer (score 0):

Based on your term "add-stock" you are storing data, so no need to add this `/{id}` in URL, and use POST method.
Try this:

```
Route::post('/add-stock','StockController@addStOCk');
```